# Update Multiple Activities - Cannot Display "Details" Field

Tags: profile, fields

I'd like to be able to update multiple Activities easily. I've prepared a Profile and have activated these fields:

- Activity Date
- Time
- Activity Status
- Subject
- Details
- Duration

All works as expected, except for the Details field which contains the Copy icon at the top of the column, but does not display the fields for each row. Instead the column is blank.

Thinking this may be an issue since Details is a text field, I added a Custom text field called Scratchpad. When added to the profile, this custom field displays as expected.

Any ideas as to why the Details field won't play along correctly?

Thanks.

We're using WordPress 4.7.3 and CiviCRM 4.7.17.[image]

Comment: Can you test on one of the demo sites to confirm this is a generic problem and not one relating to any of your plugins etc?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this with the latest WordPress and Drupal demos and got the same result. All fields included in the profile work except for Details.

Comment: Next step would be to put an issue on JIRA - and then answer your own question by saying eg 'this does not work, a feature request is now at ..... (add linkn)

Answer (score 1):

Based on above, this seems to be a minor bug or deliberate behavior. I have created an issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20433 and will close this StackExchange thread.